# Get UI element Size from Canvas in WPF Forms

Tags: c#, wpf

I instantiate new Ui elements onto a canvas like so:

```
public class MainForm :Canvas 
{
    List<BannerImage> bannerList;

    AddImages()
    {
        bannerImage = new BannerImage("title", "content");
        //accompanied with animation
        Children.Add(bannerImage);
        bannerList.Add(bannerImage);
    }
```

I need to call the bannerImages to get their current position, the following works:

```
foreach(bannerItem in bannerList)
{
   double rightPosition = Canvas.GetRight(bannerItem);
}
```

But I can't do the following:

```
bannerItem.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity) 
Size s = bannerItem.DesiredSize;
```

Which always ends up to be

```
{0,0}
```

Why is it that I can get the position of the item on the canvas but not the size?

Comment: What is the `BannerImage` class consists of?

Comment: @dhilmathy it's just a canvas with textblocks and labels inside

Comment: There is no `.NET` class called `BannerImage`, which means it's a class defined by you. So unless we know what methods/properties like `DesiredSize` and `Measure()` do, it's impossible to answer your question.

Comment: @Sach BannerImage is a canvas which is why I can call those methods

Comment: Did you implement [MeasureOverride](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.measureoverride(v=vs.110).aspx) in your control? I believe that by default `Canvas` will return 0 for it's desired size as it will size to whatever it is told. Since you have child controls in your derived `Canvas` you need to figure out what size you need and return it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am just going to take a guess that you didn't override `MeasureOverride`.  I will provide a basic implementation assuming that each element is stacked, but you would need to modify it to take into consideration your child controls and what ever custom layout you may have created (I don't know if they are in a grid, horizontally stacked, in a some kind of scrolled container, etc).

```
protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
{
    var height = 0.0;
    var width = 0.0;

    foreach (UIElement child in InternalChildren)
    {
        child.Measure(availableSize);
        if (child.DesiredSize.Width > width) width = child.DesiredSize.Width;
        height += child.DesiredSize.Height;
    }

    width = double.IsPositiveInfinity(availableSize.Width) ? width : Math.Min(width, availableSize.Width);
    height = double.IsPositiveInfinity(availableSize.Height) ? height : Math.Min(height, availableSize.Height); 

    return new Size(width, height);
}
```

**Edit**
I realized that I explained the issue in a comment, but didn't add it into my answer.  The reason you `can't get the size` is because you have to provide an override in your derived class to compute it.  By default, Canvas returns a `DesiredSize` of 0 since it will adapt to whatever size is assigned to it.  In the case of your derived control, you have a `Canvas` as the base class but you have added additional controls to it.  If you don't provide an override of the [MeasureOverride](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.measureoverride(v=vs.110).aspx) method, then the base one (the one implemented by `Canvas`) is the only one that is called.  The base `Canvas` knows nothing of your controls size requirements.  You probably also will need to override [ArrangeOverride](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.arrangeoverride(v=vs.110).aspx).  [This article](http://ikeptwalking.com/wpf-measureoverride-arrangeoverride-explained/) provides a pretty good explanation about the two methods, what they do and why you need to override them.  It also provides and example of both methods.

Comment: Ok thanks I'll take a look into this. All my elements are Canvas. So I've been doing Canvas.Add(element). I'll try this out

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I have to configure it but I think this is the right direction.